# Why JS is skipping parentNode such a "<p>"

Tags: javascript, dom

HTML:

> ```
> <div class="a">
>     <p><p class="y"><p class="z"></p></p></p>
> </div>
> ```

CODE:

```
        console.log(document.getElementsByClassName('z')[0].parentNode)
```

returns div.a

Help guys, why it skips

?? BTW if change p.y to div.y then it will return div.y

Comment: Why would this be downvoted?  It's a pretty clear question, with clear example code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `<p>` cannot be the parent of another `<p>`.  Each of your `<p>` tags implicitly ends at the start of the next one; the closing tags are ignored.

There are other tags that act like this too: `<td>` and `<li>` come to mind. (Different reasons, but the reasons have a similar effect on markup appearance.)

Answer (score 6):

Invalid html is why it is skipping. You can not have a paragraph in a paragraph.

[**HTML 4.01 specification: 9.3.1 Paragraphs: the P element**](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/text.html#h-9.3.1)

> The P element represents a paragraph. It cannot contain block-level
>   elements (including P itself).

Inspect the HTML with your console and you will see that the browser will rewrite your html to close the first paragraph tag. This is what the browser will render:

```
<div class="a">
    <p></p>
    <p class="y"></p>
    <p class="z"></p>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Should note that the reason for the extra `<p></p>` at the end is because of the markup you gave has an extra `</p>` at the end.

Answer (score 2):

Your HTML is invalid. A `p` element cannot be a child of another `p` element and the end tag for a `p` element is optional.

Thus your HTML is interpreted such:

```
<div class="a">
    <p></p>
    <p class="y"></p>
    <p class="z"></p>
    <!-- unexpected and therefore ignored </p> -->
    <!-- unexpected and therefore ignored </p> -->
</div>
```

The parent node is not being ignored. The HTML you are writing is just not generating the DOM you are assuming it will.

Answer (score 1):

paragraph tags, `<p>` are a special case in HTML. The following was perfectly valid html:

```
<p>this is a paragraph
<p>This is another paragraph, but notice I never closed the first one
<p>a third paragraph, also following another non-closed para
<p>a fourth one</p>
```

starting a NEW paragraph without closing the previous performed an implicity close of the previous one. This implies that you cannot nest paragraphs within each other.

Comment: There aren't really a *special* case. There are *many* optional tags in HTML.

Comment: @quentin: true, but there aren't many that can't be embedded inside themselves. nested lists, divs, tables, blah blah blah.